# Get ranges where values are not None

Tags: python, list

## The Goal

I would like to get the ranges where values are not None in a list, so for example:

```
test1 = [None, 0, None]
test2 = [2,1,None]
test3 = [None,None,3]
test4 = [1,0,None,0,0,None,None,1,None,0]

res1 = [[1,1]]
res2 = [[0,1]]
res3 = [[2,2]]
res4 = [[0,1],[3,4],[7,7],[9,9]]
```

## What I have tried

This is my super lengthy implementation, which does not perfectly work...

```
def get_not_None_ranges(list_):
    # Example [0, 2, None, 1, 4] -> [[0, 1], [3, 4]]
    r = []
    end_i = len(list_)-1
    if list_[0] == None:
        s = None
    else:
        s = 0
        
    for i, elem in enumerate(list_):
        if s != None:
            if elem == None and end_i != i:
                r.append([s,i-1])
                s = i+1
            if end_i == i:
                if s > i:
                    r=r
                elif s==i and elem == None:
                    r=r
                else:
                    r.append([s,i])
        else:
            if elem != None:
                s = i
            if end_i == i:
                if s > i:
                    r=r
                else:
                    r.append([s,i])
            
    return r
```

As you can see the results are sometimes wrong:

```
print(get_not_None_ranges(test1))
print(get_not_None_ranges(test2))
print(get_not_None_ranges(test3))
print(get_not_None_ranges(test4))


[[1, 2]]
[[0, 2]]
[[2, 2]]
[[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 5], [7, 7], [9, 9]]
```

So, **I was wondering if you guys know a much better way to achieve this?**

Comment: "Better" according to what criteria? Without objective requirements, "better" is entirely subjective. For code improvements, visit CodeReview.SE. SO is meant for code correction. Also, if you haven't tried it, check out a [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Comment: It could also use an algorithm description in order to determine if there's an error in design or implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

test1 = [None, 0, None]
test2 = [2, 1, None]
test3 = [None, None, 3]
test4 = [1, 0, None, 0, 0, None, None, 1, None, 0]


def get_not_None_ranges(lst):
    result = []
    for key, group in groupby(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1] is not None):
        if key:
            index, _ = next(group)
            result.append([index, index + sum(1 for _ in group)])
    return result


print(get_not_None_ranges(test1))
print(get_not_None_ranges(test2))
print(get_not_None_ranges(test3))
print(get_not_None_ranges(test4))
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1]]
[[0, 1]]
[[2, 2]]
[[0, 1], [3, 4], [7, 7], [9, 9]]
```

Comment: @2e0byo [one possibility](https://tio.run/##bVHRioMwEHzPV@yj0txhtA9Hob/QHygiFqMX0CRsVmi/3jMbq3dwPmSz4@zsDPEv@na2@vK4LD26CQxpJOfGAGbyDgkGdLN/vITodA@DpsY6am7O6gZbO@iQjYHyi4D1Qx3mkeAK95r7sQ2x@1Dc9Q7BrnNBJk0w9i0eNeRKnx5dC88LPMEEiDs2YR43yGosegJ1/Fh1m13sGNgdnK6/2KZfTVAy8peb3H@23mvbZXfeJ1mhzrd4NKPdeEKQDqRi2GhUQiHZcc14GfFSKnlA1U7lo0roOaJKFgks3hc@1AbWQsSMkR5j8l7JpUylSuWc8ng0lrLRBMr@e67IzPN8WX4A)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode indeed, but I meant *without* calculating it manually.  I did it with two filtered lists instead, but that solution is ugly so I'm not going to post it

Answer (score 2):

A non-`groupby` solution that doesn't need extra treatment for the last group:

```
def get_not_None_ranges(lst):
    result = []
    it = enumerate(lst)
    for i, x in it:
        if x is not None:
            first = last = i
            for i, x in it:
                if x is None:
                    break
                last = i
            result.append([first, last])
    return result
```

Whenever I find the first of a non-None streak, I use an inner loop to right away run to the last of that streak. To allow both loops to use the same iterator, I store it in a variable.

Comment: Very nice solution as well !

Comment: Nice! It's worth mentioning that this works because you continue to use the same iterator from the previous `enumerate()` in the inner loop, so indices aren't repeated.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Working with iterators like this has become so natural to me that I can't even quite follow your worry about repeating :-P. But I added a little explanation that I think also gets your point across.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to iterate over the list, and check for two conditions:

1. If the previous element is `None` and the current element is not `None`, start a new "range".
2. If the previous element is not `None` and the current element is `None`, end the currently active range at the previous index.

```
def gnnr(lst):
    all_ranges = []
    current_range = []
    prev_item = None

    for index, item in enumerate(lst):
        # Condition 1
        if prev_item is None and item is not None:
            current_range.append(index)
        # Condition 2
        elif prev_item is not None and item is None:
            current_range.append(index - 1) # Close current range at the previous index
            all_ranges.append(current_range) # Add to all_ranges
            current_range = [] # Reset current_range

        prev_item = item
    # If current_range isn't closed, close it at the last index of the list
    if current_range:
        current_range.append(index)
        all_ranges.append(current_range)
    return all_ranges
```

Calling this function with your test cases gives the expected output:

```
[[1, 1]]
[[0, 1]]
[[2, 2]]
[[0, 1], [3, 4], [7, 7], [9, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try. Code uses Type Hint and a named tuple in order to increase readablity.

```
from typing import NamedTuple,List,Any

class Range(NamedTuple):
    left: int
    right: int
    
def get_ranges(lst: List[Any]) -> List[Range]:
    ranges : List[Range] = []
    left = None
    right = None
    for i,x in enumerate(lst):
        is_none = x is None
        if is_none:
            if left is not None :
                right = right if right is not None else left
                ranges.append(Range(left,right))
                left = None
                right = None
        else:
            if left is None:
                left = i
            else:
                right = i
    if left is not None:
        right = right if right is not None else left
        ranges.append(Range(left,right))
    return ranges


data = [[1,0,None,0,0,None,None,1,None,0],[None,None,3],[2,1,None],[None, 0, None]]
for entry in data:
    print(get_ranges(entry))
```

outut

```
[Range(left=0, right=1), Range(left=3, right=4), Range(left=7, right=7), Range(left=9, right=9)]
[Range(left=2, right=2)]
[Range(left=0, right=1)]
[Range(left=1, right=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can solve this by using classic sliding window approach.

Here is the solution which works fine:

```py
def getRanges(nums):
    left = right = 0
    ranges, n = [], len(nums)
    while right < n:
        while left < n and nums[left] == None:
            left += 1
            right += 1
        while right < n and nums[right] != None:
            right += 1
        if right >= n:
            break
        ranges.append([left, right - 1])
        left = right = right + 1
    return ranges + [[left, right - 1]] if right - 1 >= left else ranges
```

Lets test it:

```py
test = [
    [1, 0, None, 0, 0, None, None, 1, None, 0],
    [None, None, 3],
    [2, 1, None],
    [None, 0, None],
]

for i in test:
    print(getRanges(i))
```

Output:

```py
[[0, 1], [3, 4], [7, 7], [9, 9]]
[[2, 2]]
[[0, 1]]
[[1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using first and last of each group of not nones:

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_not_None_ranges(lst):
    result = []
    for nones, group in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda x: x[1] is None):
        if not nones:
            first = last = next(group)
            for last in group:
                pass
            result.append([first[0], last[0]])
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my example. It is definitely NOT the most efficient way, but I think it is more intuitive and you can optimize it later.

```py
def get_not_None_ranges(list_: list):
    res = []

    start_index = -1
    for i in range(len(list_)):
        e = list_[i]
        if e is not None:
            if start_index < 0:
                start_index = i
        else:
            if start_index >= 0:
                res.append([start_index, i - 1])
                start_index = -1

    if start_index >= 0:
        res.append([start_index, len(list_) - 1])
    return res
```

The main thought of this function:

1. start_index is initialized with -1
2. When we meet not None element, set start_index to its index
3. When we meet None, save [start_index, i - 1 (since the previous element is the end of the session)]. Then set start_index back to -1.
4. When we meet None but start_index is -1, we need to do nothing since we have not met the not None element this turn. For the same reason, do nothing when we meet not None when start_index > 0.
5. When the loop end but start_index still larger than 0, it means we haven't record this valid turn. So we need to do that manually.

I think it may be a little bit complex, it may help to paste the code above and debug it line by line in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

How about:-

```
test1 = [None, 0, None]
test2 = [2, 1, None]
test3 = [None, None, 3]
test4 = [1, 0, None, 0, 0, None, None, 1, None, 0]


def goal(L):
    r = []
    _r = None
    for i, e in enumerate(L):
        if e is not None:
            if _r:
                _r[1] = i
            else:
                _r = [i, i]
        else:
            if _r:
                r.append(_r)
                _r = None
    if _r:
        r.append(_r)
    return r


for _l in [test1, test2, test3, test4]:
    print(goal(_l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (one-liner with `itertools.groupby`):

```py
from itertools import groupby

out = [[(v := list(g))[0][1], v[-1][1]] for _, g in groupby(enumerate(i for i, v in enumerate(testX) if not v is None), lambda k: k[0] - k[1],)]
```

---

Tests:

```py
test1 = [None, 0, None]
test2 = [2, 1, None]
test3 = [None, None, 3]
test4 = [1, 0, None, 0, 0, None, None, 1, None, 0]

tests = [test1, test2, test3, test4]

for t in tests:
    out = [
        [(v := list(g))[0][1], v[-1][1]]
        for _, g in groupby(
            enumerate(i for i, v in enumerate(t) if not v is None),
            lambda k: k[0] - k[1],
        )
    ]
    print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 1]]
[[0, 1]]
[[2, 2]]
[[0, 1], [3, 4], [7, 7], [9, 9]]
```